# Creating pairs file for images

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, text-files

I have a dataset that contains face images and I want to synthesize masks to these images and put them in another folder.
And I need to create a text file that contains pairs of the names of these images (The masked and the non-masked).

Is there any easy way to create this file in python or anything else without having to put the names manually?

Comment: Please be more precise. How does an input file look? How does a mask look? Does the program need to make the mask or does the user annotate it by hand? How does the text file look? What platform are you on?

Comment: The folder contains jpg images.. don't mind the mask, I mean that I want to manipulate the images on python (deep learning) and create a new version of them in another folder.. So after manipulating them, I want to create a text file containing pairs of the names of images before and after manipulation. (image1.jpg   image1_manipulated.jpg) and so on...